# Create vs Copy empty file, which operation is the least expensive?

Tags: php

Which method is least expensive on the server? I am dynamically creating directories and would like each of them to contain an empty html file.  Also how could one measure the difference?

```
$file = text.html;
$newDest = myDir/text.html;
copy($file, $newDest);
```

VS

```
$File = "myDir/text.html"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = ''; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data);  
print "Data Written"; 
fclose($Handle);
```

Comment: Have you done some benchmark?

Comment: Have you considered http://php.net/touch ?

Comment: @ceejayoz - should be an answer, because touch is almost certainly more efficient and less resource expensive than either of the OPs options

Comment: thanks for the article but the test says 'file_put_contents' is 2x faster than touch

Comment: If you've benchmarked it, **why are you asking this question?**

Comment: i did not benchmark it,  the link you sent over had the benchmark.  i dont know how to benchmark php.  (not yet)

Comment: Regarding the "benchmark". He is running **100** iterations, and he probably only ran it once. It's not a benchmark worth taking notice of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy operations are generally very expensive for a variety of reasons.  I ran the following operations each 1000 times to compare them:

```
 copy
 touch
 fopen, fwrite, fclose
 fopen, fclose //this still creates the file
 fopen //files closed automatically, but this may take up more memory.
```

`touch` is consistently twice as fast as any `fopen` method (all were around the same speed).  `copy` was always the slowest.

In terms of memory, `fopen` probably uses more since you have to store the file handle while `touch` and `copy` only return booleans.

In summary, use `touch`.

Answer (score 4):

[touch](http://php.net/touch) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) are almost same. And they fall in the same speed level. I did some benchmark with following functions.

```
define('MAX_ITERATION', 10000);

function create_empty_fpc($name) {
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/create_fpc/$name", "");
}

function create_empty_fopen($name) {
    if($fh=fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."/create_fopen/$name", "w"))
    fclose($fh);
}

function copy_empty($name) {
    copy(dirname(__FILE__).'/empty', dirname(__FILE__)."/copy/$name");
}

function touch_empty($name){
    touch(dirname(__FILE__)."/touch/$name");
}
```

### Result

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
| Script name             | Execution time in seconds |
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
| With create_empty_fopen | 1.4960081577301           |
| With create_empty_fpc   | 1.2142379283905           |
| With copy_empty         | 1.4280989170074           |
| With touch_empty        | 1.0558199882507           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
```

### Conclusion

touch is fastest. After that file_put_contents. copy and just creating an empty file is almost same speed.

Answer (score 1):

**I believe this would be the least expensive:**

```
$file = "path/filename.html";
touch($file)
  or die("Error creating '$file'.\n");
echo "'$file' created\n";
```

**How to measure the difference:**

Measuring the execution time of code is called *profiling* and is done with a *profiler*. The optional [*xdebug*](http://xdebug.org/index.php) module [provides profiling](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

In a pinch you could attempt to measure it directly in PHP thusly:

```
$start = time();
// ...
$end = time();
$executionSeconds = $end - $start;
echo "Completed in $executionSeconds seconds.";
```

Note: I wouldn't expect this to be particularly accurate or useful. Use of a profiler is your best choice.